# Propagate selected language to subinstaller with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have a master Inno Setup installer in which I can choose a language. In the `Run` section, I launch a sub-installer (also made in Inno Setup).

When the second installer is launched, I would like use the the language chosen in the master installer.

So I pass in parameter the language.

Now, in the `Code` section I would like get the language in parameter and set it.

MyMainProgram.iss

```
Filename: "{tmp}\MySubProgram_setup.exe"; StatusMsg: "Installing My Sub Program"; \
    Parameters: "/Language ""{language}"""
```

In `MySubProgram.iss` I can have the language with that : `{code:GetCommandLineParam|/Language}` or `language := GetCommandLineParam('Language')`

But I don't know how to set the language.
Thanks

Comment: *"witch I can choose a language"* - Are you referring to the standard Inno Setup language mechanism/dialog? Or some other "language"? - If the first, why are you using a custom `/Language` switch, if there's a standard `/LANG` switch? - If the latter, you have to tell us, where do you keep the selected language stored in the main installer.

Comment: In my main program, yes the user can select a lnaguage with the inno setup language dialog. I don't know `/LANG` . How to use it in my main program and get it in my sub progrm and set the language?

Comment: And the sub program (sub installer), does it also use the standard Inno Setup language dialog?

Comment: No, I don't want it to appear because the language has been selected in the main program.

Comment: Sure, we understand that! But what does it do currently?

Comment: My software need several little components to work. So the MainProgram is used in order to select the components I wish to install. All my component has his own .iss

Comment: That's hardly a clear answer to my question. But I hope I understand. Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that both installers use the standard Inno Setup language mechanism/dialog, just use the [`/LANG` command-line switch](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=LANG) (for the child installer) and set it to the value of [`{language}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=language) (in the master installer):

```
[Languages]
Name: "en"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "de"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl"

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\MySubProgram_setup.exe"; StatusMsg: "Installing My Sub Program"; \
    Parameters: "/LANG={language}"
```

The subinstaller does not need any additional code. It just need to have the same languages defined:

```
[Languages]
Name: "en"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "de"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl"
```

[image: German]

[image]